# Setting up Pulumi on GitHub Codespaces with Devcontainers Universal

Tags: docker, pulumi, vscode-devcontainer, github-codespaces, devcontainer

I am looking to setup Pulumi on GitHub Codespaces and this is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/universal

RUN sudo apt update

# Install Pulumi
ENV PULUMI_ROOT "$HOME/.pulumi"
ENV PATH "$PULUMI_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
RUN curl -fsSL https://get.pulumi.com | sh
```

There are official Devcontainer templates provided on public forums and the official Pulumi repository, but I need to specifically use the `mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/universal` image only. After it gets set up, the `pulumi` CLI isn't available until I manually install it again.